# I can't start a Symfony project in PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

After 3 years I start using PhpStorm again, my first think is using Symfony 4.x with PhpStorm. But I can't start any project from Terminal on MacOS Mojave.

I have installed all plugins: Symfony, PHP Annotation, PHP Toolbox

Also I have install Symfony from Terminal also Composer.

When I search with `ls` in the Terminal Symfony isn't shown there.
In Finder I can see it as hidden file `.symfony`
trying to go in the director like `cd /.symfony` also not found also does not work

Comment: Can you see your files in PHPStorm? Do you test with PHPStorm terminal for serving php ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are speaking about the `symfony` cli which does not have anything to do with PHPstorm.

Go to https://symfony.com/download and install the symfony cli

`curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash`

The `symfony` cli should work without any problems after following these steps.

EDIT:

Don't forget to follow the steps written after installing the cli

```
Add this to your shell configuration file:
  export PATH="$HOME/.symfony/bin:$PATH"
Start a new shell, and then run 'symfony'
```

you have to add that line at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: thanks, I have install the Symfony cli, but still the same issue.

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   614    0   614    0     0    729      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   729
100 7891k  100 7891k    0     0   736k      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 1397k
  Uncompress binary...
  Making the binary executable...
  Installing the binary into your home directory...
  The binary was saved to: /Users/semihxxx/.symfony/bin/symfony
The Symfony CLI v4.7.0 was installed successfully!

Comment: Semihs-MacBook-Pro:~ semihxxx$ ls
Applications  MEGAsync Downloads _TyranoGameData
Daz 3D   Movies   __MACOSX
Desktop   Music   composer.phar
Documents  PhpstormProjects eclipse
Downloads  Pictures  eclipse-workspace
Game   Projects  glassfish5
Library   Public   home

Comment: Semihs-MacBook-Pro:~ semihxxx$ composer create-project symfony/skeleton the_spacebar
-bash: composer: command not found
Semihs-MacBook-Pro:~ semihxxx$ 
  [Restored 30 Sep 2019 22:17:09]
Last login: Mon Sep 30 12:51:11 on ttys000
Restored session: Mon Sep 30 21:32:16 +03 2019
Semihs-MacBook-Pro:~ semihxxx$

Comment: this was I have if I still try to create a project

Comment: Are you sure that you followed the steps ? post edited

Comment: can you help me with creating the new shell?